# Opencart. Как вывести мужские, женские и детские товары на разных страницах?

Tags: opencart

Возникла необходимость создать страницы с мужскими, женскими и детскими товарами. Принадлежность прописана в характеристиках товара. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: 1. Создать разные страницы. 2. В соответствии с характеристиками товара, отображать его на разных страницах.

Answer (score 0):

Исходите из простой аксиомы - хороший сайт это прежде всего правильная **структура**. Это и удобство пользователя и хороший ранк в поиске. Структуру при которой вы торгуете несколько отдельных групп товаров (трусы для мужчин и трусы для мальчиков это разный товары!) через единые каталоги и разделяете их только по характеристикам, неверна и её необходимо менять. Потратьте пару дней, но приведите структуру меню в порядок. Примерно так:

```
menu:

| нижнее бельё | среднее бельё | верхнее бельё | и т.д.
  -- мужское
     -- трусы
     -- носки
     -- майки
     -- наборы
     -- и т.д. 
  -- женское
     -- трусы
     -- носки
     -- майки
     -- наборы
     -- и т.д. 
  -- детское
     -- трусы
     -- носки
     -- майки
     -- наборы
     -- и т.д.
```

Характеристиками товара делайте, собственно, его характеристики: ткань, размер, вес, возраст, цвет и т.д. (для игрушек можно и возраст выводить в отдельные подкатегорию). В опции - цветовые и размерные варианты и т.д.

Если такой подход по каким-то причинам вам не подходит, то самым верным будет искать модуль фильтр под opencart с возможностью фильтрации по характеристикам. Или писать/заказывать у разработчиков.